# How do you eager-load records with Elasticsearch::Model.search() across multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-rails

Using the elasticsearch-rails/elasticsearch-model gems.

I know you can do the following with the proxy on a single model:

`MyModel.__elasticsearch__.search(search_hash).records.includes(:my_association)`

I need to search across similar models which contain the same association I want to eager-load.  The following errors out though with 'undefined method'.

`Elasticsearch::Model.search(search_hash, [MyModel, MyOtherModel]).records.includes(:my_association)`

Both `.records` calls seem to return an `Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Records` object, but it seems that `.includes` is only valid with a single model through the ES proxy.

Is there a way to easily do this when searching across multiple models?

Answer (score 0):

Use a delegate. Here's an example from dimroc:
[Eager Loading Delegate](https://gist.github.com/dimroc/ccc6c80c747ee8f957f3)